# Getting brackets when compiling ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

My node js file

```
app.get("/", async(req, res) => {
  const shortUrls = await ShortUrl.find();
  const url = await ShortUrl.find({
    realEmail: email
  });
  res.render("index", {
    shortUrls: shortUrls,
    url: url,
    userEmail: profile._json.email,
    userName: profile.displayName,
    id: profile.id,
    async: true
  });
});
```

My code is below:

```
<tbody>
  <%url.forEach((shortUrl) => { %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="<%= shortUrl.full %>">
          <%= shortUrl.full %>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="<%= shortUrl.short %>">localhost:3000/<%= shortUrl.short %></a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= shortUrl.clicks %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= shortUrl.GivenEmail %>
    </tr>
    <%})%>
</tbody>
```

When I run this i get the following on my site.
[image: 'this is what I am seeing on my site.]

Does anyone know why this is happening? Please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just remove async property from `app.js` and it will work